# Social links in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Every time I try to set a social link for example to yigg i get messed up links in adress bar

It looks like this  `http%253A%252F%252Fbleibgesund.org%252Farchiv%252Fzitate%252F`

And it schold be `http://bleibgesund.org/archiv/zitate/1000-krankheiten-nur-eine-gesundheit/328`

It does not matter what plugin for social bookmarking I use. They have all the same problem.

I searched for solution in internet but still not found a solution.

Anybody an idea what could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is getting encoded to be passed through a the API URL. That's normal. I tried the social links on the page you used there and they worked. Where isn't it working?

Comment: I removed not working links of couse. :) For test I can put them on. Thank for your response.